# Is it possible to define a variable so it available to every function within the class

Tags: php, function, class, variables, scope

Is it possible to define a variable so it's available to every function within the class...

For example:

```
class scope {

  private $db = null;

  function __construct($db) {
          $this->db = mysqli_init();
          return $this->db;
  }

  function uses_variable {
          $stmt =  $db->stmt_init();
  }

}
```

But without making the variable global or using a bunch of extra unnecessary code or overheads ?

Edit

I'm loading all classes on to my index using something like this:

```
class autoloader {
    public static $loader;

    public static function init()
    {
        if(self::$loader == NULL) {
            self::$loader = new self();
        }
        return self::$loader;
    }   

    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array(this, 'library'));
        request::request();
        template::render();

    }

    public function library($class) 
    {
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/lib');
        spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');
        spl_autoload($class);
    }


}
```

When I call the variable in the uses_variable function I am presented with an error if I do so like this:

```
function uses_variable () {
     $stmt =  $this->db->stmt_init();
}
```

`Notice: Undefined property: autoloader::$db`, it might be worth noting that the function user_variable is called on another class that has been loaded with the auto-loader and I wonder if this changes my projects scope, I'm still learning ><.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work. The problem is that you are accessing `$db` in the `uses_variable()` scope. Use `$this->db` instead.

```
function uses_variable () {
     $stmt =  $this->db->stmt_init();
}
```

Should solve your issue if you have any, but I guess its not "copy/paste" code in your question.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use $db in the functions, usually mysqli_stmt_init, I want to preserve db = mysqli_init() or am I missing something ?, would $this->db still hold the same value or would it be re appended to stmt_init ?

Comment: You should test it. `$this->db` will always have the same value or reference.

Comment: This is not working, I have an error Notice: Undefined property: parentclass::$db the class that the function I use this in is loaded by autoloader along with others, and the function it throws an error from is called in another class, could this be causing the error ?

Comment: @FatalCleric you must provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do. We cannot guess what you are doing, and your question is currently about basic class structure. The error seems to refer to a parent class, possible you try to use `parent::$db` - which does not work with `self` scope.